# Is returning from a noreturn function undefined behavior, if it returns with a call to another noreturn function?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, noreturn

Let's say that I'm making an application which will be long lasted, and not expected to terminate for any normal reasons (e.g. user terminates application, e.x.: an HTTP server).

I mark `main` itself with the C++11 standard attribute `[[noreturn]]`, indicating that it must never return control back to the callee without aborting or throwing an exception.

```cpp
[[noreturn]] int main(
    int const argc,
    char const * const[] argv
) { ... }
```

I start off by parsing the CLI arguments, and then pass what data was extracted into my "real" main function, where more of the work continues.

The other function, we'll call it `realMain`, is also marked as `[[noreturn]]`.

In my code, I gave the `main` function a return statement into `realMain`, and promptly recieved a generic Clang warning about returning from a noreturn function.

```cpp
[[noreturn]] int realMain(Data const data) {
    ...

    std::cerr << "Unreachable!" << std::endl;
    std::abort();
}

[[noreturn]] int main(...) {
    ...
    auto const parsed_cli_args = parse(argv, argc);
    ...

    return realMain(parsed_cli_args);
}
```

Is it safe to return into other noreturn functions, or is this undefined behavior?

(and unrelated, may any compilers take advantage of this? e.g. making `main` directly jmp instead of call `realMain`?)

Comment: @Casey Improving the title *is* appreciated, as long as it wouldn't completely change the question.

Comment: @ilkkachu `main` is the function that returns, `realMain` aborts or exits the program before ever reading the end of it's body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to return into other noreturn functions, or is this undefined behavior?

I wonder if there's some language confusion here.

I'm not sure if you mean if it's UB for `main()` to return using the hypothetical return value from `realMain()` which it never should get; or if it's UB for `realMain()` to return back to `main()`.

Anyway, based on the example on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn) which Casey linked to:

```
void q [[ noreturn ]] (int i) {
  // behavior is undefined if called with an argument <= 0
  if (i > 0) {
    throw "positive";
  }
}
```

I would understand that merely having that `return realMain();` in `main()` is not UB. It's just UB if `realMain()` ever actually returns. And by that point, it doesn't matter what `main()` does, it's already UB since `realMain()` broke the "noreturn" promise first.

But since neither is supposed to ever return, I don't understand why you'd write the `return` in any case, instead of e.g. just leaving the call to `realMain()` as the last statement of `main()`, without a return.

Comment: A situation may arise where a function's last action is to make a tail call through a passed-in function pointer, and it will sometimes receive pointers to functions that return and sometimes receive pointers to functions that don't.  From a [[noreturn]] perspective, what matters is whether there is any sequence of events that would result in control returning to the caller of a [[noreturn]] function.

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior. As specified in the C++ standard:

> 9.12.9 Noreturn attribute               [dcl.attr.noreturn]
>
> If a function f is called where f was previously declared with the
> noreturn attribute and f eventually returns, the behavior is
> undefined.

Whether or not the function returns by returning the result of another `[[noreturn]]`-attributed function is immaterial.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. This answer suggests that it's not undefined behavior. Since the other noreturn function never returns (per the very section you cited), then a function that does not return unless a noreturn function returns also never returns.

Comment: Does C++ standard define the order of calling and returning (or leave it unspecified), in such a way that the function may return before `realMain` has returned?

Answer (score 0):

[Yes.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn)

(Emphasis mine)

> Explanation
>
> Indicates that the function does not return.
>
> This attribute applies to the name of the function being declared in function declarations only. **The behavior is undefined if the function with this attribute actually returns.**
>
> The first declaration of the function must specify this attribute if any declaration specifies it. If a function is declared with [[noreturn]] in one translation unit, and the same function is declared without [[noreturn]] in another translation unit, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Comment: Can you clarify which statement you are referring to when you say "yes"? Thank you in advance.

Comment: From where is the quote?

Comment: @JadenGarcia The bolded portion of the quote.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "Yes" is a link to the source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn